# Edit XML with Eclipse productively

Tags: xml, eclipse

I find XML editor of Eclipse is very unproductive (new child or attribute must be inserted by context menu), and the text editor for XML is lack of hints.
Are there any plugins or tricks that can make XML editing in Eclipse productively?

Comment: "the text editor for XML is lack of hints"... what does that mean? It has auto-completion...

Comment: Oh, my bad. Under the XML editor there's two tab: Design and Source. Go to Source tab give me auto-completion.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the XML text editor to have auto-completion then your document needs to reference a schema (XSL). The schema will tell the editor what the correct tags are and where they can be used, and Eclipse should then offer you auto-completion.